# Determining unused values in a M:N database system

Tags: mysql, sql

This problem consists of a database system relating components to their suppliers with corresponding costs, which are used to build widget assemblies.

Here is the database and tables:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DB;

USE DB;

CREATE TABLE components (
    c_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name_c VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (c_id)
);

CREATE TABLE suppliers (
    s_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name_s VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (s_id)
);

CREATE TABLE widgets (
    w_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name_w VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (w_id)
);

CREATE TABLE assemblies (
    w_id INT,
    c_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (w_id)
        REFERENCES widgets (w_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id)
        REFERENCES components (c_id)
);

CREATE TABLE prices (
    p_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    s_id INT,
    c_id INT,
    cost INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (p_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (s_id)
        REFERENCES suppliers (s_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (c_id)
        REFERENCES components (c_id)
);

insert into components(name_c)
    values('C1');
insert into components(name_c)
    values('C2');
insert into components(name_c)
    values('C3');
insert into components(name_c)
    values('C4');
insert into components(name_c)
    values('C5');
insert into components(name_c)
    values('C6');

insert into suppliers(name_s)
    values('S1');
insert into suppliers(name_s)
    values('S2');
insert into suppliers(name_s)
    values('S3');
insert into suppliers(name_s)
    values('S4');
insert into suppliers(name_s)
    values('S5');

insert into widgets(name_w)
    values('A1');
insert into widgets(name_w)
    values('A2'); 
insert into widgets(name_w)
    values('A3');  
insert into widgets(name_w)
    values('A4');

insert into assemblies(w_id, c_id)
    values(1,1);
insert into assemblies(w_id, c_id)
    values(2,2);
insert into assemblies(w_id, c_id)
    values(2,3);
insert into assemblies(w_id, c_id)
    values(3,4);
insert into assemblies(w_id, c_id)
    values(3,5);
insert into assemblies(w_id, c_id)
    values(4,6);
insert into assemblies(w_id, c_id)
    values(4,3);

insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(1,1,121);
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(1,2,135);
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(2,2,94);    
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(2,3,155);
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(3,3,178);
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(3,4,199);
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(4,4,122);
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(4,5,155);
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(5,5,133);
insert into prices(s_id, c_id, cost)
    values(5,6,184);
```

The resulting tables are as follows:

components

```
c_id | name_c
 1     C1
 2     C2
 3     C3
 4     C4
 5     C5
 6     C6
```

(Note: tables components, suppliers, and widgets all defined analogously such that widgets with 1-A1, 2-A2, etc. and suppliers with 1-S1, 2-S2, etc.)

prices - list of supplier-component cost combinations

```
p_id s_id c_id cost
1     1     1   121
2     1     2   135
3     2     2   94
4     2     3   155
5     3     3   178
6     3     4   199
7     4     4   122
8     4     5   155
9     5     5   133
10    5     6   184
```

assemblies - list of components used to build the widget assemblies

```
w_id | c_id
  1    1  
  2    2  
  2    3 
  3    4  
  3    5  
  4    6  
  4    3
```

For the first part, with help I was able to determine the correct query to find the minimum-cost outputs with respect to assemblies as follows (objective was to determine the minimum-cost components to build each widget assembly):

```
select w.name_w, sum(price_min.min_cost) as min_cost
from widgets as w 
left join assemblies as a on a.w_id = w.w_id 
left join (select c_id, min(cost) as min_cost from prices group by c_id) as price_min on price_min.c_id = a.c_id 
group by w.name_w 
order by w.w_id
```

Output:

```
 name_w  min_cost  
 A1     121
 A2     249
 A3     255
 A4     339
```

However, I'm stuck trying to figure out how to determine which suppliers (name_s) are not used in this cost optimization (i.e., did not provide a competitive component price to be used in the corresponding widget-assembly build incorporating those suppliers' components). Working out on paper, I expect the following result:

```
 name_s
 S3
```

But I can't seem to get this result using SQL (specifically MySQL)...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should also add  an input ( a data sample) as tabular text

Comment: Good call, done above. Thanks!

Comment: Put your minimum cost outputs into a temp table.  Then you can do all sorts of things with the results.  Use a JOIN between results and name, and utilize NOT IN to determine which names are not in the minimum cost analysis.

Comment: That's the process I've been trying to follow, but I keep getting stuck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified from the query for finding the minimum cost:

```
select distinct s.name_s
from suppliers s
left join
prices p
on s.s_id = p.s_id
where p.s_id not in (
select distinct s_id from prices p1 -- suppliers of low cost components
inner join
(select a.c_id, price_min.min_cost
  from widgets as w 
  left join assemblies as a on a.w_id = w.w_id 
  left join (select c_id, min(cost) as min_cost from prices group by c_id) as price_min 
  on price_min.c_id = a.c_id ) t -- component price details before sum()
on p1.cost = t.min_cost and 
   p1.c_id = t.c_id  )
```

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thanks so much for your help! I'm still learning the ropes with SQL, but this was a very insightful solution. Really appreciate it!